# How to prevent loggin in via ssh as my domestic user?

Tags: server, ssh, password, authentication

Hi i am kind of a newb in `ssh` but i setup a domestic server in a laptop. I have a user called e.g. USERBRUNO with a password authentication required. The problem is that if my friend does ssh USERBRUNO@myip he can login and write and read my files without ever having to authenticate with the USERBRUNO password or any at all. I am using `RSA` authentication method. I added his key. I have the correct (i hope) configs in the `sshd_config` such as

```
PasswordAuthentication YES 
RootLogin NO
StrictModes YES
```

I really need to get a hang at this. Thanks.

Comment: i'm  not able to understand meaning of  `I added his key` .  is this your friend key ?.

Comment: do you want users to ssh into your system or not, if you do not want them to ssh and you use the system locally then stop sshd, else configure a passphrase with your rsa so only people with the correct passphrase will be able to log in, having passwordauthentication as yes means that those who do not have public key will be asked for password, not the other way round.

Comment: @pl_rock i added his RSA key to the authorized keys file

Comment: @Ads i have an apache server running there so i want to be able to login via SSH. My friend is working with me on the server so i want him to be able to login as well but i created a local account for him with his name and put it in the sshonly group. What i want is that he can be able to upload via SSH and if needed run some commands but i want him restricted to his account.

Comment: Just remove his key from `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: It should be a single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using windows to log in to the server or linux? the process will be different, if you add your friends public key to your profile he will get access to your files, what you may want is to add his public key to his user profile, /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys and change permission to 600 to be readable by the user. give him access to webfiles by adding him to www-data group, and set youself as the owner of files by `sudo chown -R yourname:www-data /var/www/public_html/` and 
`sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/public_html/` make sure you change the directory and username appropriately.
If you configure to change Password Authentication to 'NO' in /etc/ssh/sshd-config and restart the ssh service by `sudo service ssh restart` the plain text password authentication will be disabled, be warned that first test that the ssh authentication is working before closing the session  or you may be locked out, for more security you can change the default port to something greater than 1024, and X11 forwarding to no. for more information read this article - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Comment: Make sure you use a passphrase in ssh key so it is more secure.

Comment: Thanks dude that was exactly what i meant. Thanks for helping.